# How can I read different types of a Json in Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, xamarin, types

Here's my code, I send a request to my data base who send me back a list of dictonary, that I can read if they are string but cannot for an other type, what can I change in my code to read every type ?

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> reponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>>(json);
                List<Dictionary<string, string>> resultat = reponse["reponse"];

                foreach (Dictionary<string, string> dicoProfil in resultat)
                {
                    //Initialisation des variables
                    string nomProfilAAjouter = dicoProfil["Usager"];
                    string nomPropriete = dicoProfil["Predicat"];
                    string valeurPropriete = dicoProfil["Caracteristique"];
                    string dataProperty = dicoProfil["Dataproperty"];
                    string valeurdata = dicoProfil["Valeurdata"];

                    //Modification du profil si un profil avec le même nom existe déjà
                    if ("profil:"+nomProfil==nomProfilAAjouter)
                    {
                        if (profils.ContainsKey(nomProfilAAjouter))
                        {
                            await SetProperty(nomPropriete, valeurPropriete, dataProperty, valeurdata, profils[nomProfilAAjouter]);
                        }
                        //Ajout du profil
                        else
                        {
                            Profil newProfil = new Profil();
                            await SetProperty(nomPropriete, valeurPropriete, dataProperty, valeurdata, newProfil);
                            profils[nomProfilAAjouter] = newProfil;
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
            return profils["profil:" + nomProfil] ; 
        }
```

Here's what I try to read:

[{'Usager': 'profil:Jean_PIERRE', 'rdf:type': 'owl:NamedIndividual', 'profil:A_Pour_Comportement': 'profil:9e7b483e_cec8_4ce7_8ae2_6e693859a043', 'profil:A_Pour_Droit': 'profil:Administrateur', 'profil:A_Pour_Espace_Travail': 'arch:IfcSpace_12783', 'profil:A_Pour_Habitude': 'profil:7228afa0_ce7b_4b76_a640_6e2ec2cbcb23', 'profil:A_Pour_Profession': 'profil:Responsable_informatique', 'schema:givenName': 'Jean', 'schema:name': 'PIERRE', 'profil:A_Pour_Competence': [{'caracteristique': 'profil:Cuisine', 'valeurdata': '4', 'predicat': 'profil:Niveau_expertise'}, {'caracteristique': 'profil:Réseau', 'valeurdata': '7', 'predicat': 'profil:Niveau_expertise'}], 'profil:A_Pour_Modèle_Usager': [{'caracteristique': 'modele:ac63f979_aa26_4bf5_a308_b1d30bd9cbae', 'valeurdata': 'Modèle_Lum_Jean', 'predicat': 'modele:Description'}, {'caracteristique': 'modele:ac63f979_aa26_4bf5_a308_b1d30bd9cbae', 'valeurdata': 'Modèle Lumiere Jean', 'predicat': 'modele:Nom'}, {'caracteristique': 'modele:f95314a6_ffc8_4481_95a6_0ed2db5e4854', 'valeurdata': 'Modèle_Temp_Jean', 'predicat': 'modele:Description'}, {'caracteristique': 'modele:f95314a6_ffc8_4481_95a6_0ed2db5e4854', 'valeurdata': 'Modèle Temperature Jean', 'predicat': 'modele:Nom'}]}]

Here's the error I get:

An error occurred: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'reponse[0].profil:A_Pour_Competence', line 1, position 545.'. Callstack: '  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue (Newtonsoft.Json.ReadType readType)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to read does not map to your dictionary. Because you have some properties alongside with an array. I'd suggest to define your own object type to map your json. Here's an example:

```
public class MyClass {
   [JsonProperty("Usager")]
   public string Usager { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("rdf:type")]
   public string RdfType { get; set; }
 // other properties
   [JsonProperty("profil:A_Pour_Competence")]
   public List<APour> A_Pour_Competence { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("profil:A_Pour_Modèle_Usager")]
   public List<APour> A_Pour_Modèle_Usager{ get; set; }
}

public class APour {
   public string Caracteristique{ get; set; }
 // other properties
}
```

Depending on JSON library you are using, Attribute name may be different. i.e.: Use `[JsonPropertyName]` for `System.Text.Json`

Then use it as

```
var reponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>(json);
// omitted rest of your code
```